# Error while adding Secure social 2.0.12 dependency

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I am trying to add SecureSocial 2.0.12 dependency in play framework but when i compile it i am

getting a Resolve Exception:unresolved dependency:securesocial # secure social_2.10;2.0.12:not

found...

i am using play 2.0.4.

Comment: Can you show us you `Build.scala` file? BTW this should not be on Stackoverflow but on the issue tracker of secure social.

Answer (score 2):

The procedure outlined at http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html works fine for me. However, there's no released version of *securesocial* for Scala 2.10. You say you're using Play 2.0.4, which is based on Scala 2.9, but you're attempting to resolve a 2.10 version of *securesocial*. Are you *really* using 2.0.4?

**EDIT (3 May, 2013)**: *securesocial* appears to be available for Scala 2.10 now, as version `master-SNAPSHOT` or `2.1-RC4`. See http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/webapp/search/artifact?1&q=securesocial